# How to do a rtrim() to a Android Cursor query?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have the following query:

```
Cursor c = sd.query(itemsTable.Table_Name, columns, itemsTable.ItemNumber + "= ?", selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

I need to be able to do this:

```
'SQL Query I am running on the database using for testing
select * from items where rtrim(itemnumber) = '292664'
```

Where itemnumber is my selectionArgs.

The SQL query returns the correct results but the cursor query returns null.

I would rather not change the way I am running queries and would like to know if there is a way to convert my existing query to work the same as the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
String selection = "RTRIM(" + itemsTable.ItemNumber + ") = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"292664"}; // or whatever
Cursor c = sd.query(itemsTable.Table_Name, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

Comment: When I run with this I get:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x823cf0

Comment: I fix it by removing the ' before and after the ?.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case. I'll correct the post.